# Generate Uniform Distribution of Floats in Javascript

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to generate random numbers in javascript that are evenly distributed between 2 floats. I've tried using the method from the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#getting_a_random_number_between_two_values) to get a random number between 2 values but it appears to cluster on the upper end of the distribution. This script:

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function median(values) {
    if (values.length === 0) throw new Error("No inputs");

    values.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });

    var half = Math.floor(values.length / 2);

    if (values.length % 2)
        return values[half];

    return (values[half - 1] + values[half]) / 2.0;
}

const total = 10_000_000
let acc = []
for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    acc.push(getRandomArbitrary(1e-10, 1e-1))
}
console.log(median(acc))
```

consistently outputs a number close to .05 instead of a number in the middle of the range (5e-5). Is there any way to have the number be distributed evenly?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** changed script to output median instead of mean.

Comment: The middle of the range is not `5e-5`. The middle of the range is `1e-10+(1e-10 + 1e-1)/2`, which is closer to `5e-2`

Comment: When you do as many iterations as you are doing you are nearly always going to get a result that is very close to the mean

Comment: Ah, ok. I guess what I mean is that I want the numbers evenly distributed over the log scale.

Comment: @ControlAltDel the _median_ is also near .05 . Will update the script.

Comment: @lights "the median is also near .05..." that is what I am saying

Comment: @ControlAltDel Might not be understanding something, but the way I'm envisioning this is that on a number line between 1e-10 and 1e-1 there is way more space under 0.05 than over it. So shouldn't the numbers be evenly distributed across that space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function log10(x) { return Math.log(x)/Math.LN10; }

function getLogRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.pow(10, log10(min) + (Math.random() * (log10(max) - log10(min))));
}

function median(values) {
  if(values.length === 0) throw new Error("No inputs");
  let a = [...values].sort((a,b)=>a-b);
  return a[Math.floor(a.length/2)];
}

const iterations = 1_000_000;
let a = [];
for (let i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
  a.push(getLogRandomArbitrary(1e-10, 1e-1));
}

console.log(median(a));
console.log(log10(median(a)));
```